# Listing the minimum price products for current month

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have a table called "fiyatlar" in a MySql database. Table contains multiple product id's and prices per month and year. Please check the example table below:

```
ID      Price     Month    Year
11111   11.00     5        2016
11111   12.15     6        2016
11111   13.10     7        2016
22222   8.75      5        2016
22222   8.50      6        2016
22222   8.00      7        2016
```

I need to find the minimum priced products for current month and list them in a datagrid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I haven't figure out the mysql query yet. So i didn't tried anything yet.

Comment: `the minimum priced products` if not THE (1)  minimum priced, how many?  largely just a matter of SQL

Comment: So from your sample, what are you expecting as output from the query?

Comment: Regarding to the sample table above, the product which's id 11111 is not the minimum price for current month (assuming the current month is 7) but id 2222 has the minimum price for current month. So simply it has to ignore 1111 and add 2222 to the datagrid. Basically i only need to check the current month and if it's price is the minimum value untill this month than add to datagrid, else ignore and move to next id.

Comment: @Ardeth I created your sample table and verified my answer gives the lowest priced item for the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE based on newly understood requirements:**

I couldn't stand not solving this. :) This will work:

```
SELECT fiyatlar.ID
FROM fiyatlar INNER JOIN
    (SELECT ID, MIN(Price) AS Price
    FROM fiyatlar GROUP BY ID) AS tmp
ON fiyatlar.ID = tmp.ID
    AND fiyatlar.Price = tmp.Price
WHERE Year = YEAR(current_date())
    AND Month = MONTH(current_date());
```

This was my test table for repeating minimum values:

```
11111   12.15   6   2016
11111   11.00   5   2016
11111   10.90   10  2015
11111   10.90   7   2016
22222   9.00    9   2015
22222   8.75    5   2016
22222   8.70    7   2015
22222   8.50    6   2016
22222   7.90    4   2015
22222   7.70    8   2015
22222   7.70    7   2016
33333   8.99    1   2016
33333   7.80    2   2016
33333   3.90    3   2016
33333   5.90    4   2016
33333   7.90    5   2016
33333   5.90    6   2016
33333   3.90    7   2016
```

Comment: Dear Topshop. Thank you for the answer but unfortunately not working correct. It brings only one product and not the cheapest one in the list :)

Comment: You said you only wanted 1 product for each month, and it does pull back the cheapest given your sample table above. I just tested it.

Comment: he actually never clarified that. `the minimum priced products` (note the plural **s**)  could mean the 5, 3 or 1 lowest priced item.

Comment: no you got me wrong tho. assume that i have more than 500 products and each product has it's own price per month and year. I need to get the products if it's price is the cheapest one untill now on the current month. There may be more than one product which have the best value in the list for the current month.

Comment: In your comment you said if an item was not the cheapest for the month then skip it. So why don't you show what you want as a full result set given your sample so there's no more confusion.

Comment: I think I know what you want. If for example in your sample data 11111 had dropped down to 10.50 for month 7, you would want BOTH 11111 and 22222 to be returned. Is that correct?

Comment: well to make it more clear i am sharing the table here [link](http://expirebox.com/download/6ea3fdb2e62ba335d99940ba09b35a84.html)... I need to find the product(s) if it's price is the cheapest current month from the beginning.

Comment: @Ardeth Sorry, I don't have any more time to work on this. MySql doesn't seem to want to group the same way I can in Oracle so it looked like I was going to have to move to using a stored procedure to be able to process it properly.

Comment: @Ardeth My updated answer is tested to pull all items whose lowest price occurs only in the current month and year.

Comment: @topshot The code works perfectly great but only thing is it's not bringing the minimum values repeating. For example; an id has the minimum value in month 3 and also the same minimum value in month 7. How can we update it?

Comment: @Ardeth It works for me. See my edit for values I used for testing. Give me an example where it doesn't work.

Comment: @topshot I've added 3rd product with same minimum prices in two different months. If you run your query you'll see that it will not bring the 3rd product because it has same minimum price in different months. But actually it has the best price in this month too.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing differently, but that still works for me. I updated my test data set with what it sounded like you were doing and made it so 22222 did not have cheapest price this month and it selected 11111 and 33333 as you would expect. **Edit**: I see you had suggested an edit already. I used different values but exact same concept you had shown. 33333 had lowest overall price (7.50) that was duped in months 3 and 7.

Comment: I'd be tempted to delete the first part of this answer

Answer (score 0):

If this what you have in mind?

```
SELECT *
FROM
(SELECT *
FROM fiyatlar
WHERE Year = YEAR(current_date())
AND Month = MONTH(current_date())) month_table
WHERE Price = MIN(Price)
```

Comment: yes it's what i need for but it gives an #1111 - Invalid use of group function error